# Ultraviolet light material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

How could I make a black light material out of this one?

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Blacklight itself is not visible to the human eye. Do you want to achieve the effect some materials have when they are lit by UV-Light? Or do you simply want to color some plastic the way it is in your picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got some results using this method: emission + inverted ColorRamp.

Using Eevee + Bloom the result looks immediately better, but I still have to fine-tune it for cycles. Problem is that either the light emitted is too weak or the bulb gets too white. I've also tried Filmic Blender with similar results.

[image: nodes and result in cycles]